# Visual Studio for Mac Layout not allow 'drag'n'drop' objects from toolbox

Tags: xml, layout, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

MacBook Pro M1, Ventura 13.2.1
VS for Mac 17.5.4
Xamarin Android 13.2.0
When I drag anything (say Button, Text, Layout) from the Toolbox into the layout xml or onto the design view, it just disappears (it actually flies back to the toolbox).
Double click on item also does not work - nothing happens.

Only way to make layout - write XML manually. There was same question 4 months ago, still can't find solution :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio for Mac Layout not allow 'drag'n'drop' objects from toolbox

I tested it and exactly as you described. It's the issue of VS for Mac. And I also see you have reported [it](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Layout-drag-and-drop-from-Toolbox-not-wo/10347301?q=Layout+not+allow+%27drag%27n%27drop%27+objects+from+toolbox). You can keep following it.

Also as you said: Only way to make layout - write XML manually so far. For me, I do this all the time.

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed my bad suspicions.

Comment: My case is closed on Microsoft because "Low priority". Even without any suggestion or workaround. Just additional question - may be any standalone xml-layout-maker for Androidnexist?

Comment: @Zpaulis *May be any standalone xml-layout-maker for Androidnexist?*  It most likely is, and I've noticed that other similar questions have been marked as low priority :(